# Как сгруппировать данные в столбце

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Как в google таблицах сделать группировку данных по значению в столбце?

Пробую так

> =QUERY(Data!$A$2:$A$1000;"select A, SUM(A) group by A")

P.S.: поиск в google не помог, в стандартном excel(не online) группировка есть, а в онлайн версии какие-то странные способы. Может быть есть разрешение какое-то или формула?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя из условия следует получит следующий результат (на примере `Google Таблицы`):
Исходные данные (наименование листа `Лист1`):

[image: Исходные данные]

Результат группировки:

[image: Результат группировки]

1-ый способ:

1. использовать функцию `SUMIF` (`СУММЕСЛИ`), которая находит сумму содержимого ячеек, соответствующих определенному условию;
2. Для группировки и суммирования столбца `Значения` по `1` будет формула следующего вида  `=sumif(A2:A9;C2;A2:A9)` , где

2.1. `A2:A9` - `диапазон`, в котором осуществляется поиск ячеек, удовлетворяющих условию;

2.2. C2 - условие для поиска ячеек в `диапазоне`. В нашем случае `1`;

2.3. A2:A9 - диапазон, ячейки которого суммируем.

[image: Формула группировки]
[Справка по функции SUMIF() от Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)

2-ой способ:

3. Использовать `Сводные таблицы`.
4. Выбираем пункт меню `Данные` - `Сводная таблица`;
5. Создается лист `Сводная таблица ...`
   [image: Сводная таблица]
6. В `Редакторе отчетов` добавляем:

6.1. в категории `Строки` наименование столбца `Значения`(лист `Лист1`);

6.2. в категории `Значения` поле  `Значения` (лист `Лист1`) (совпадение наименование (`Значения`) категории и наименования столбца). По умолчанию устанавливается функция `SUM` (суммирование значений).
Получаем результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Справка о создании Сводной таблицы от Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=ru)

Comment: Особо не вникал в ответ, так как давно писал вопрос, но пожалуй отмечу как правильный, человек старался писал =) Решал я через подсветку и какие то другие условия вынося данные в отдельный столбец по формулам. уже не помню какие